# "Splitting" Terms of an Infinite Sum

Tags: summation, functional-equations

One interesting method that can be used to evaluate infinite sums
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x)$$
is to find a function $g(x)$ that has the property
$$g(x)-g(x+1)=f(x)$$
because if we substitute this into the infinite sum, it telescopes and we are left with just $g(1)$ as the value of our sum.

For example, consider the sum
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x}=1$$
if we let
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2^x}$$
then we have
$$g(x+1)=g(x)-\frac{1}{2^x}; g(1)=1$$
and we can conclude that
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2^{x-1}}$$
so the value of the sum is $g(1)$, which is $1$.

Can anybody think of any other ways to "split up" functions that are less easy to split than exponential ones? Like polynomials or rational functions?

Comment: You can do that with $ f(x) = x^n $. For that, we can use $ g(x) = x^{n+1} $. Of course, $ g(x + 1) - g(x) = (x + 1)^{n+1} - x^{n+1} \ne x^n $, but it is a polynomial of degree $ n $, which means you can find the sum of $ f(x) $ if you have all the sums of powers less than $ n $.

Comment: This is much the same as evaluating integrals using antiderivatives. Trigonometric functions of arithmetic progressions can be done using the prosthaphaeresis formulae.

Comment: Assuming $g(x)\to 0$.

Comment: Note that when you can write $f(x)=g(x)-g(x+1)$, there is a nice closed form for the finite sum $\sum_{x=1}^{n} f(x) = g(1)-g(n+1)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I'm getting at is that there are a lot of summation problems that have nice closed form solutions, but it is difficult to evaluate them this way - rather, I usually have to use different methods to get them to collapse. What I'm asking for is some method that I can use to apply this strategy to a wider variety of functions.

Comment: @Frpzzd Typical  partial fraction decomposition: $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\,$.

Comment: What about $\frac{1}{x2^x}$? Can you split that up?

Comment: Taking these ideas further: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Answer (score 0):

Such a series is called a telescoping series.

For example $$\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}3$$, which may be written $$\sum_{i=1}^n {}_iP_2=\dfrac{{}_{n+1}P_3}{3}$$ or $$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{i}2=\binom{n+1}{3}$$. This generalises: $$\sum_{i=1}^n {}_iP_r=\dfrac{{}_{n+1}P_{r+1}}{r+1}$$ or $$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{i}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$